# How do you calculate the big oh of the binary search algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, binary-search

I'm looking for the mathematical proof, not just the answer.

Comment: _The_ BigOh is kind of meaningless. Even O(n) is _a_ correct answer for this one. You are probably interested in _the_ Theta...

Comment: meaningless - are you kidding?  O(n) being correct has nothing to do with Big-O being meaningless or not.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [recurrence relation of binary search is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Application_to_common_algorithms) (in the worst case)

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + O(1)
```

Using [Master's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem)

[image]

- n is the size of the problem.
- a is the number of subproblems in the recursion.
- n/b is the size of each subproblem. (Here it is assumed that all subproblems are essentially the same size.)
- f (n) is the cost of the work done outside the recursive calls, which includes the cost of dividing the problem and the cost of merging the solutions to the subproblems.

Here a = 1, b = 2 and f(n) = O(1) [Constant]

We have f(n) = O(1) = O(n<sup>log<sub>b</sub>a</sup>)

=> T(n) = O(n<sup>log<sub>b</sub>a</sup> log<sub>2</sub> n)) = O(log<sub>2</sub> n)

Comment: @cfarm54: Binary search is in O(log n).

Comment: @cfarm54 : I was framing the answer. BTW the time complexity of binary search isn't O(nlog n), its O(log n)

Comment: Nitpick: The recurrence relation you give is the recurrence for the _worst case_.

Comment: @Aryabhatta : Thanks for reminding. Mentioned that in the post. :-)

Comment: i thot data set already in place and so f(n) would just be the comparison.

Answer (score 9):

The proof is quite simple: With each recursion you halve the number of remaining items if you’ve not already found the item you were looking for. And as you can only divide a number *n* recursively into halves at most log<sub>2</sub>(*n*) times, this is also the boundary for the recursion:

> 2·2·…·2·2 = 2<sup>*x*</sup> ≤ *n* ⇒ log<sub>2</sub>(2<sup>*x*</sup>) = *x* ≤ log<sub>2</sub>(*n*)

Here *x* is also the number of recursions. And with a local cost of O(1) it’s O(log *n*) in total.