# Time complexity of tree search with three children at each node

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree

In the case of a Binary search tree, the time complexity of finding an element is `O(logn)` as one each iteration, elements to be searched is halved. But if there is a tree with a maximum of three children under each node and consider we have some condition which branch to search next among the three branches, then what will be the time complexity. In this case, the element to be searched is reduced by 1/3 each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094864/how-do-you-calculate-the-big-oh-of-the-binary-search-algorithm/6094889#6094889) and understand why for binary tree the recurrence relation is

`T(n) = T(n/2) + O(1)`

In case where tree has 3 nodes or more generally k nodes, the same relation will be

`T(n) = T(n/k) + O(1)`

Follow along that answer and you will come to know that for any k-ary tree, the binary search will take O(log<sub>k</sub>n)

Answer (score 1):

I would say what that the complexity would be O(log<sub>3</sub>N) given the fact that you *have some condition which branch to search next among the three branches*.

With every iteration you are reducing by 3-fold the number of remaining iterations in the worst case scenario.